# Why isn't $data reference working in this example?

Tags: javascript, ajv

I have set the $data option to true, and am trying to limit endDate to be at least the value of the startDate using a $data expression. This example should fail validation, but it does not. :(

```
var Ajv = require('ajv');
var ajv = new Ajv({allErrors: true, $data: true});

var schema = {
  "properties": {
    "filter": { "properties": {
        "startDate": { type: 'string', format:'date'},
        "endDate": { type: 'string', format:'date', formatMinimum: {'$data': '/filter/startDate'}}
  }}
}};

var validate = ajv.compile(schema);

test({filter: {startDate:'2008-09-01', endDate: '2004-09-01'}});

function test(data) {
  var valid = validate(data);
  if (valid) console.log('Valid!');
  else console.log('Invalid: ' + ajv.errorsText(validate.errors));
}
```

I have tried various JSON pointers.. `0/startDate` `1/startDate` and the shown `/filter/startDate` and all of them result in the same Valid! response.

I expect an Invalid response with a message about endDate needing a minimum of the startDate, but I'm getting a Valid! response.

You can see a running example at https://runkit.com/jcdietrich/5d0a45ced5afb8001c33808b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`formatMinimum` is not supported by the base ajv package. ajv-keywords is required.

```
var Ajv = require('ajv');
var ajv = new Ajv({allErrors: true, $data: true});
require("ajv-keywords")(ajv)

var schema = {
  "properties": {
    "filter": { "properties": {
        "startDate": { type: 'string', format:'date'},
        "endDate": { type: 'string', format:'date', formatMinimum: {'$data': '/filter/startDate'}}
  }}
}};

var validate = ajv.compile(schema);

test({filter: {startDate:'2008-09-01', endDate: '2004-09-01'}});

function test(data) {
  var valid = validate(data);
  if (valid) console.log('Valid!');
  else console.log('Invalid: ' + ajv.errorsText(validate.errors));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first number in a Relative JSON Pointer is the number of "levels to go up". You can think of this as doing `cd ..` in the terminal (sort of - read the RFC linked below for the actual workings, as exact behaviour depends on whether you're within an array or an object.)

In your case you want to go up once to `endDate` and then once again to `properties`; two times in total. Then you "go into" `startDate`, which is where the forward-slash comes in...

```
2/startDate
```

You can read about how Relative JSON Pointers work in [this RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-luff-relative-json-pointer-00#section-5.1).

Comment: I tried 2/startDate as well.. see the following for a running example... https://runkit.com/jcdietrich/5d0a45ced5afb8001c33808b